# Update git commit message automatically to the corresponding file

Tags: git, commit

Is it possible to update the commit message along with version number to the file directly? That is, When the pushed file is opened from the GIT, it should contain the commit message along with the version number.

Comment: It may be me, but I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Could you provide more details as to what you want your commit message to look like?

Comment: When should the file be changed? Before commit (and therefore the change already in the repo) or only after checkout?
In the later case a `post-checkout` should be a possible solution.
In the first case I'm not sure but IMHO a `post-commit` is executed before the commit message is available for your changes.

Comment: I’m confused.  Do you want to use the file as a commit message?  Are you trying to have a commit message template?  Are you trying to update a file with some data when you make a commit?  Can you provide an example of what you want to help folks answer your question?